# template and abstract class

Tags: c++, class, templates, abstract-class

I have this abstract class in fsm.h:

```
template<class step_type> class fsm {
    protected:
        step_type   step;
        step_type   step_old;
        step_type   step_tmp;
        bool        step_pulse;
        char        name[256];
        class fsm   *next;
    public:
        fsm(step_type);
        void set_name(char *parent, char *myname);
        void test();
        virtual void update() = 0;
        void show(){cout << step << ' ' << step_tmp << '\n'; };
        void init(step_type st_current) {step = st_current;};
        class fsm   * get_next (void) {return (next); }
        void set_next (class fsm *x) { next = x; }
};
```

and the derived class:

```
class deri_taglio : public fsm<taglio_steps>{
    private:
        bool    cmd_prelevamento_done;
        bool    cmd_scorrimento_done;

    public:
        deri_taglio(): fsm<taglio_steps>(ST_TAGLIO_CUT_PANEL){
            cmd_prelevamento_done = false;
            cmd_scorrimento_done = false;

        };
        void update(){cout << "deri_taglio\n";};

};
```

but if I define a pointer to the abstract class in a master class:

```
class fsm_master {
public:
    fsm *first;
};
```

I have this error...
 ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘fsm’ with no type

Comment: `fsm` isn't a type; it's a template. You need to use `fsm<taglio_steps> *first`.

Comment: BTW, destructor of the abstract base class should be `virtual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your abstract class happens to be a template - which means it doesn't really define a type. this is unlike the `deri_taglio` class, that actually defines a type - because it instantiates the abstract class when deriving (by giving the template parameter an actual value, `fsm<taglio_steps>`.

Either you'll need to define an actual type for this purpose, like:

```
fsm<taglio_steps> *first;
```

Or you'll need to create an abstract class that is an actual type by itself, e.g. by removing anything `step_type` from it.

Comment: the second is not possible because I need the fields ste_type

Answer (score 0):

How about to create a real abstract class like this?

```
class abstract {
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
}

template<class step_type> class fsm : public abstract {
    ...
}

class fsm_master {
public:
    abstract *first;
};
```

Comment: I need to implement the update in the master class...thanks but for my program it's not a possible solution